# Spawn Point in End Portal

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In *Minecraft* I used the command `/setworldspawn` and built an end portal around it. So whenever I leave the end, it spawns me there(on the end portal) thus I'm taken back to the end. What should I do? Any help is greatly appreciated as this was my Redstone testing world.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `/setworldspawn <x> <y> <z>`. Try replacing the `<x> <y> <z>` with coordinates that are not inside the portal.

Comment: Thanks @nelsonwtm. But the problem is I didn't know where that spawn position was. Anyways, I used blockmann multiplayer for mcpe to teleport to my spawn point(the original one) and I killed myself. Now I'm back in the overworld. But thanks anyway.